Azure Synapse SQL Server Partition Switch - Partition Integrity
I am learning about Partition Switching from the book 'Azure Data Engineer Associate Certification Guide'.
I have question regarding a code example in GitHub Repo. Below is the code.
My first question: The alter statement below is transferring data from TripTable to TripTable_20220101, but does TripTable_20220101 has only 1 partition boundary defined instead of the three boundaries defined for TripTable. Is this according to standard practice?
ALTER TABLE dbo.TripTable SWITCH PARTITION 2 TO dbo.TripTable_20220101 PARTITION 2 WITH (TRUNCATE_TARGET = ON);

My second question: Why did TripTable_20220301 had to have 3 partition boundaries here instead of just 1 boundary like the TripTable_20220101 table.
ALTER TABLE dbo.TripTable SWITCH PARTITION 4 TO dbo.TripTable_20220301 PARTITION 4 WITH (TRUNCATE_TARGET = ON);


In the first scenario, while having only one partition boundary for a partitioned table isn't standard, switching partitions between tables with differing boundaries is feasible if table definitions align. The provided code successfully switches a partition from TripTable to TripTable_20220101 due to matching definitions.
In the second scenario, TripTable_20220301 possessing three partition boundaries, unlike TripTable_20220101, suggests tailored data storage requirements or user-query performance considerations driving the design.

It is not typical to define only one partition boundary for the target table when using the SWITCH PARTITION statement.
However, in the provided code example, the table TripTable_20220101 was created with just one partition boundary to match the partition being switched out.
This is necessary because the SWITCH PARTITION statement requires both the source and target tables to have the same partition scheme and function.
In this scenario, since the partition being switched out was for a single date, the TripTable_20220101 table was also created with a single partition boundary for that same date.
For example I hve tried  below example:
CREATE TABLE Sales
(
    [SaleID] INT NOT NULL,
    [SaleDate] DATE NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] INT NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price] DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX,
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH([SaleID]),
    PARTITION ([SaleDate] RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES
        ('2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01')
    )
);

This above table is partitioned by the SaleDate column with three partition boundaries for the months of January, February, and March in the year 2022.
If we want do partition switching
and want to remove the data for the month of January and add the data for the month of April.
You can try the below approach:
Create a temporary table with the same partition scheme and partition function as the Sales table,
but with only one partition boundary for the month of January:
CREATE TABLE Sales_January
WITH
(
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX,
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH([SaleID]),
    PARTITION ([SaleDate] RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES
        ('2022-01-01')
    )
)
AS
SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE 1=2;

